# How to enable a shipping method for a specific SKU?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, overrides, shipping-methods, plugin

I'd like to create a module to enable the **Table Rate Shipping Method** if a product with a specific SKU is the customer cart.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using below code.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface">
        <plugin name="table_rate_check" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ShippingPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**ShippingPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


class ShippingPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * Hide FlatRate shipping method
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface[] $methods
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface[] $methods
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress(\Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject, $methods) 
    {
        foreach($methods as $key => &$method) {

            if($method->getMethodCode() == 'tablerate') {
                if($this->checkTableRateShipping()) {
                   unset($methods[$key]);
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $methods;

    }

    private function checkTableRateShipping()
    {
        $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $showTableRate = false;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
          if($item->getSku() == "SKU which needs to be allow") {
             $showTableRate = true;
             break;
          }
        }
        return ($showTableRate) ? false : true; 

    }


}
```

Make sure you have enabled table rate shipping method from admin. Let me know if any more help needed. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi @Rafael, Was it helpful for you?

Comment: Hi @Ramkishan, this was very helpful! Any tips on enabling it on a per-item basis? I implemented this with flat rate, but only want the flat rate charged for the sku(s) in the code. Currently, all products are charging a flat rate even if one qualifies. Any thoughts?